# how to stop macros running when opening a Word document using OLE Interop?

Tags: ms-word, office-interop, com-interop

As the title suggests, I have a .Net application which uses interop to open documents in Word. I have set

`app.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable`

before opening the document. According to the documentation, thhis "Disables all macros in all files opened programmatically, without showing any security alerts"

However, when I attempt to open one specific document I get a dialog box on the screen that says "could not load an object because it is not available on this machine". It's a customer document but I believe it contains a macro with references to a COM object which I don't have installed.

Am I doing something stupid? is there any way to *actually* disable macros when opening a Word document?

Comment: Andy, if  the question was answered could you please mark it as such?

Comment: @Cindy I'm sorry but this was a long time ago and I'm no longer working on that project. Normally I'm the type of person who would have put the solution here if I got it working, but I honestly can't remember.

Comment: There is an answer posted below the question to which you did react. I was made aware of it due to a similar question having been asked last week. It would be nice to be able to use this as a "confirmed" duplicate since it contains so much useful information in both the Q and the A, which is why I asked...

Comment: Yes, agree is it a useful topic. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code I was working on, and the link in the answer is broken :-(

Answer (score 3):

Try:

> WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 1

Bizarrely, this relies on a throwback to pre-VBA days, but still seems to be the most-reliable way to ensure that no auto macros are triggered (in *any* document - you may want to turn it back using the parameter "0").

I recently had a project where I had to process 6,000 Word templates (yes, templates, not documents) many of which had oddball stuff like macros, etc. I was able to process all but 6 using this technique. (I never did figure out what the problem was with those 6).

---

EDIT: for a discussion of how to call this from C#, see: http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/56/281785.aspx

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea how I can call this from C# ?

Answer (score 1):

For c# you can use

`(_wordApp.WordBasic as dynamic).DisableAutoMacros();`

The whole code I'm using is:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
private Word.Application _wordApp;
...
                    _wordApp = new Word.Application
                {
                    Visible = false,
                    ScreenUpdating = false,
                    DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone,
                    FileValidation = MsoFileValidationMode.msoFileValidationSkip
                };

                _wordApp.Application.AutomationSecurity = MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
                (_wordApp.WordBasic as dynamic).DisableAutoMacros();
```

Comment: You can review this article about old WordBasic
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/word.application.wordbasic