# Ignore an "external" error when opening a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm attempting to copy the contents of a word document, but the document has embedded vba which causes a compile error anytime I open it.

The error reads

> "The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems."

I expect this error to occur, so how do I tell my vba code in Access to ignore the errors *without* changing the word doc?

My vba code so far - the `DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone` does not work, neither does setting it to False:

```
Private Sub cmdQuickLtr_Click()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
Dim doc As Object
Set doc = wApp.Documents.Open(Me.tbLetterPath.Value)
doc.Content.Copy
doc.Close

'do something with the copied content

wApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
Set doc = Nothing
Set wApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you edit the code in document to be opened? It probably has declarations which need to be made pointer safe: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ptrsafe-keyword

Comment: Irrelevant to the 64bit error, you are mixing early and late binding in your code. Since you have declared `Dim wApp As Word.Application`, you can simply new-it up: `Set wApp = New Word.Application`. To use late binding, declare the `wApp` as object and remove the reference to MS Word.

Comment: Does this help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224592/how-to-stop-macros-running-when-opening-a-word-document-using-ole-interop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to stop macros running when opening a Word document using OLE Interop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224592/how-to-stop-macros-running-when-opening-a-word-document-using-ole-interop)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit the code in the doc to be opened. There are hundreds with identical macros - none of which are pointer safe.

I tried using both the original and the suggested code in freeflow and Cindy's link. Neither of them bypass the error messages.


It's not ideal, but if I could just get a way to ignore the error 40036 that access stops on, I wouldn't mind clicking OK to dismiss the Word error. I just need the vba in access to continue.